# Is it true that a machine that generates thrust without blowing anything out not invented yet?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

If yes. Am I correct to to say such machine does not conflict with the law in Physics and thus, it can be possibly invented?

I mean a machine that does not rely on external forces such as a machine floating in a vacuum.

Comment: Newton’s third law ensures all internal forces result in zero displacement of centre of mass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a machine is impossible as it violates conservation of momentun. If an object accelerates, it gains momentum in the direction of the force. In order to conserve momentum, something must receive an impulse in the opposite direction. This can be the machine itself, in which case it doesn't accelerare, or the air, water, ground, etc. Thus it is impossible to have a machine that accelerates without exerting a force on something else.

Comment: ok so even if there is an energy source inside the machine. that energy can never be used or manipulated to make the machine move forward unless something is thrown out.

Comment: Yeah exactly, energy and momentum are both conserved separately. Even if there is an energy supply, it cannot violate conservation of momentum.

Answer (score 0):

Electromagnetic motors do not create exhaust gases however they require electric energy and convert it into mechanical energy + heat (due to friction). 
The electric energy can be achieved by using a battery (chemical source).

Hope this clarifies.